# AJAX Request Too Long / Bad Request

Tags: javascript, ajax

Greetings Everyone

I am using the following code to send data to update to a php file. The problem is I get a Request Too Long issue. I have used the 'POST' method I believe if thats the right way. Yes the data I am sending is quiet huge. So what can I do?

```
   var link = 'updateFirstPost.php?post_id='+id+'&first_post='+encodeURIComponent(text);


    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        var  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
                refreshPost(div_post, thread_id , id);
    }
}

    xmlhttp.open("POST",link,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

The problem is I get a Request Too Long issue. I have used the 'POST' method I believe if thats the right way. So what can I do?

Comment: You are putting the data as GET parameters into the URL, which will always cause them to be sent inside the URL. You need to add them as POST data

Comment: i guess your server is responding too slow ...

Comment: @Pekka : whats the other way to solve it? I am not used to JQUERY

Comment: @experimentX : I have tested it thoroughly. Only happens when I send huge data.

Comment: you mean when `text` is too long ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are putting the data into the URL, which will always cause them to be sent as GET data. GET requests have natural length limitations on both the server's and the browser's side.

To send the data through POST, you need to put the parameters like so:

```
var params = 'first_post='+encodeURIComponent(text); 

....

http.send(params);
```

(stolen from [here](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php))

If this is not for learning purposes, consider using a JS framework like jQuery. It makes stuff like this much, much easier and  less code-intensive.